Finding $\sum\sum_{0\le i<j\le n}~~ j~ {n\choose i}$
The purpose of this post is to correct the answer for this double sum
$$S_n=\sum\sum_{0\le i<j\le n}~~ j~ {n\choose i}$$
in some places and also to ask for any other alternate method of solving it.
We can write it as
$$S_n=\sum\sum_{0\le i<j\le n}~~ j~ {n\choose i}=\sum_{i=0}^n {n\choose i}\sum_{j=i+1}^n j.$$
Let $k=j-i$, then
$$S_n=\sum_{i=0}^n {n\choose i}\sum_{k=1}^{n-i} (k+i)=\sum_{i=0}^n {n\choose i}\sum_{k=1}^{n-i} (k+i)=\sum_{i=0}^{n} \left[ \frac{(n-i)(n-i+1)}{2}+(n-i)i\right] {n \choose i}.$$ By changing $i \to n-i$, we get
$$S_n=\sum_{i=0}^{n} \left[ \frac{i^2+i}{2}+(n-i)i\right] {n \choose i}$$ $$=\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=0}^n [-i^2+i+2ni]{n \choose i}.=\frac{1}{2}n2^{n-2}[-n-1+2+4n]=n(3n+1)2^{n-3}.$$
In some places $S_n$ is mistakenly reported to be $n(n+3)2^{n-3}.$
The question is: What could be other methods to find this double summation?

Check these: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3611850/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1673953/42969

I'm pretty sure that the following doesn't meet your definition of "other methods" but using Mathematica (and probably MATLAB and Maple and other symbolic algebra systems) has Sum[j  Binomial[n, i], {i, 0, n - 1}, {j, i + 1, n}] resulting in $2^{n-3} n (3 n+1)$.

Thanks for checking.
